# Unable to save data into excel 2010 entered by macro vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a workbook which has multiple sheets. In one of the sheets I have written a macro which creates drop-down values in another sheet (with pre-defined cells) once you click an active-x button.

Now the problem is once I run the macro it executes perfectly but once I delete the macro the drop-down values disappear even though I saved the file before deleting the macro.

Let me know if further details are required.

Code Snippet -

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'Define the variables
Dim vRangeDefined, vRowCount, vCounter, vCellValue As String, vDataValue As String
Dim wbk As Workbook

'Define the range where the values are entered
vRangeDefined = ActiveSheet.Range("A:B").Value
vRowCount = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For vCounter = 2 To vRowCount
    vCellValue = vRangeDefined(vCounter, 1)
    vDataValue = vRangeDefined(vCounter, 2)

   'Assign the names to cells as per the range
    Sheets(2).Select
    ActiveSheet.Range(vCellValue).Select

    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:=vDataValue
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With

Next

MsgBox "Process complete..."

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: Further details are required :). Please show us the relevant code.

Comment: @DougGlancy Added now :)

Comment: Could you give some information about data in Range A1:B2. I checked you code and there are no problems on my computer. Maybe the reason is somewhere in the data.

Comment: And the dropdown values really disappear right when you delete the macro? They are there right before and they're gone right after?

Comment: @DougGlancy - Yes I think so. I will give some more details on the workflow shortly.

Comment: @KazJaw - I am unable to attach the spreadsheet because it will violate the IPR :) But I will find a way out soon so that the sheet can be presented here.

Answer (score 0):

What I need are only four values of cells from range A1:B2 which you can simply type here.

I am sorry for that post (started with text in line above) as I wanted to add it as a comment and I failed when doing on my mobile. Therefore I continue here...

I did everything what you described and nothing unusual happens, there are no problems which you have. I did test on Excel 2010. My further suggestions are:

1. Please think if you do any additional operation after the macro is deleted which could have seemed not important in this situation,
2. try to disconnect your macro from your button and put it into standard Module (e.g. Module1) and run it with F5 key from VBA editor.

Please inform us if you finally find the solution.

Comment: Here you go, ignore the double quotes please.

`"F5416" "Yes, No"`
`"F5639" "Yes, No"`

Comment: I am also not very sure what is happening wrong. It seems to be a problem with the spreadsheet (s/s) and not with code. The s/s is .xls it has got few locked cells, validations etc. Thanks for your help anyways Kaz!

Comment: I have an idea after your comment... Look, there are two types of .xls files. If I saved the file with .xls which is 'Excel 5.0/95' I lost all validations in cells. But when I saved as .xls for Excel 97-2003 all cells stay intact. Please check it.